# Solving the equation $\operatorname{Powerset}(X)=\varnothing$

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, set-theory, soft-question

There are (at least) two variants of this question.

Is it possible to modify the axioms of set theory, without arriving at obvious contradiction, in such a way that in a model of the theory there is a set $X$ with empty powerset? (Note that this requires quite serious changes, e. g. $X\subseteq X$ shall not hold)

Category-theoretic version: is it possible to adjoin to an elementary topos an object $X$ with an isomorphism $\Omega^X\cong0$ without collapsing the topos? (The analog of the above parenthetic remark here is that one obviously has to seriously change the structure, maybe even work in categories-without-identity-morphisms)

In response to a comment below I must admit such sort of thing requires at least some motivation. I'll try to provide some, risking even more downvotes - it is less-than-half-serious; but then it is a soft question anyway.

Recently I encountered an inductive construction which goes like this (I omit details). One constructs $X_0\subseteq X_1\subseteq X_2\subseteq\cdots$; one starts with $X_0=\varnothing$; having constructed $X_n$, elements of $X_{n+1}$ are certain pairs $(\chi,x)$ with $\chi$ something that is not relevant here, and $x\subseteq X_n$, which **for $n>0$** must satisfy $x\nsubseteq X_{n-1}$.

So out of vanity urge I thought - would not it be great if one would have some such $X_{-1}\subseteq X_0$ which would enable one to remove the above "for $n>0$"? That is, $X_{-1}$ should be such that $X_{-1}\subseteq X_0$ and moreover $x\subseteq\varnothing$ with $x\nsubseteq X_{-1}$ would not exclude $x=\varnothing$, and moreover $\{x\subseteq X_{-1}|\text{whatever}\}$ should be $\varnothing$.

As you see initially I did not dare to add one more requirement that this $X$ should satisfy: it must be subset of the empty set :D

Comment: Sorry, but I am going to say it: Why??

Comment: how do you even make sense of $\Omega^X$ in a category without identities ? you will also need to deal with the problem of the empty subobject and the singleton map... In the end the object you'll produce will have nothing to do with a topos anyway. so unless you do something like adding a  $X \rightarrow 0$ with no maps to $X$ I don't really see a way out..

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if you could do something of the sort in a category or set theory whose internal logic, instead of being classical or intuitionist, is given by (Girard's) linear logic. I think in a [$*$-autonomous category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/*-autonomous_category), e.g., given by Chu's construction, you can get an object $X=\top$ that satisfies $Z^X=0$ for every $Z$ (because this is just $Z\otimes 0 =0$). (contd.)

Comment: (contd.) The question is then whether such a category might have a subobject classifier, or rather, something reminiscent of one. Someone should have studied this question of defining linear-logic analogues of toposes, but I can't find anything.  Maybe this is just daydreaming.

Comment: I don't think getting rid of identities in the category will help you; not only the identity $X\to X$ but also the unique morphism $0\to X$ from the initial object will give a subobject of $X$ that ought to be classified by a morphism $1\to\Omega^X$.  And if you get rid of the initial object 0, then you need to rephrase the desired isomorphismn $\Omega^X\cong0$.

Comment: @MatthiasLudewig I'll add some motivation (of sorts)

Comment: If you are interested in a conceptual definition of this increasing sequence of sets, it is not necessary to change fundamental rules of set theory and category theory: Tell us all the details of this definition and we will certainly be able to make it (more) conceptual for you, i.e. to get rid of this case distinction.

Comment: I feel obliged to post [this](http://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/set-theory) here